# How to represent typeof(Int32&) type in DynamicMethod Emit

Tags: c#, cil, emit, dynamicmethod

I have the following code:

```
    delegate void RefAction(ref Int32 i);// use ref keyword
    static RefAction CreateRefGenerator(){
        // How to represent typeof(Int32&)type in here??
        Type[] types ={ typeof(Int32)};
        var dm = new DynamicMethod("RefAction"+Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), null, types, true);
        var il = dm.GetILGenerator();
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Nop);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_S,10);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Stind_I4);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        return (RefAction)dm.CreateDelegate(typeof(RefAction));
    }
```

After running, get the following error:

Because its signature or security transparency is incompatible with the signature or security transparency of the delegate type.

The following normal work:

```
  static RefAction CreateRefGenerator(){
        Type[] types = { typeof(Int32).MakeByRefType() };
        ...
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use the [`Type.MakeByRefType` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makebyreftype(v=vs.110).aspx) to create your ref type.

> Returns a Type object that represents the current type when passed as a ref parameter

---

Also there is probably an error in your il code: Afaik a dynamic method is always static, therefore the first explicit argument can be found at index zero and not one.

Comment: Runtime error:Operation may damage run-time stability.

Comment: @Kenny This answer is correct. The first argument is `typeof(int).MakeByRefType()` and is located at the index zero, thus should be loaded with `ldarg.0`. That works for me. If you want multiple references, emit the code in a loop.

Comment: Kinda sad you can't do typeof(ref T), though I suppose enforcing proper stack scoping for it would've been a chore.